# Laravel bundle zip

Tags: installation, bundle, laravel

Hi i have reached bundle parts in La-ravel tutorial. I have a simple doubt which you might easily clear. where to place the bundle zip before using the command ( ie in which directory)

php artisan bundle:install bundle

Your reply will be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Bundles go in the bundle directory under the root of the project.

Alternatively, you can install the bundle using

```
php artisan bundle:install bundlename
```

Where bundlename is the name of the bundle you want to install. This is the preferred method for installing them.

Comment: i.e. if you're using `php artisan bundle:install bundlename` you don't need to download or place the zip file anywhere. Artisan will do that all for you.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying a little for me BenjaminRH